# the number of group homomorphism

Tags: group-homomorphism

How many group homomorphism are there from  $ \mathbb{Z}_{20} $ onto $ \mathbb{Z}_{8} $? How many are there to $ \mathbb{Z}_{8} $ ?

In first question is onto but second question is to what is the difference between two question?

Comment: "onto" implies you're looking for a surjective homomorphism, while the second could be a homomorphism where the image is a subgroup (subring? you didn't specify) of $\mathbb{Z}_8$.

Comment: In the first case you need surjections, in the second case, not.

Comment: i.e in the first case$ |Im( \phi )|$=8 but in second case this is not necessary

Comment: there is one thing apply that $ |\mathbb{Z}_{20}|=|Im(\phi)|.|Ker(\phi)|$ how can i prove any reference